# SQL query to select specific fields, process sum and count from two tables

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

i have these two tables

**ORDERS**

```
id   order_id   e_id   e_name 
1    1000       1001   Tom
2    1009       1001   Tom
3    1010       1001   Tom
4    1011       1002   Parker
5    1012       1002   Parker
6    1013       1003   Rohan
```

**Transactions**

```
id  order_id  amount  status 
1   1000      100     success
2   1009      80      success      
3   1010      100     failed 
4   1011      50      success
6   1012      50      success
7   1013      100     failed
```

i would like to join two tables, select fields, process sum count and filter like this

```
  e_id   e_name  amount_sum  total_counts total_success_amount  success_count
  1001   Tom     280         3            180                   2
  1002   Parker  100         2            100                   2
  1003   Rohan   100         1            0                     0
```

this is what i tried

```
use card;
SELECT COUNT(orders.order_id) as `total_counts`, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN transactions.status = 'success' THEN 1 END) as `success_count`, 
SUM(0 + transactions.amount) as `amount_sum`, orders.e_id, 
orders.e_name 
FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN transactions  
ON transactions.order_id=orders.order_id
GROUP BY (orders.e_id), (orders.order_id),  
(orders.e_name), (transactions.amount), (transactions.status);
```

i tried many queries also not able to achieve it. Suggest me query to get my operation.

Comment: Please don't tag every DB system, tag the one you are using. What happens when you run the query you provided, error, wrong results, something else?

Comment: I don't think you want to be grouping by anything other than orders.e_id and orders.e_name.

Comment: and then not sure if `COUNT(CASE WHEN transactions.status = 'success' THEN 1 END)` will work, it might, but I'd probably do `SUM(CASE WHEN transactions.status = 'success' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: @dave so i have write separate query to get it.

Comment: `use card;
SELECT COUNT(orders.order_id) as total_counts, 
SUM(CASE WHEN transactions.status = 'success' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as success_count, 
SUM(0 + transactions.amount) as amount_sum, orders.e_id, 
orders.e_name 
FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN transactions  
ON transactions.order_id=orders.order_id
GROUP BY (orders.e_id), 
(orders.e_name);`

Comment: @Rlco Why are you using SUM(0 + transactions.amount)?

Comment: To get zero amount where there are no values you need `coalesce(sum(transactions.amount, 0)`